# Implement array Data structure in c#

Tags: c#, .net

I know it may sound silly , but I am learning c# and was just curious to create class to implement array ds in c#. I tried using indexers but end up creating another list in my class like:

```
class Arr
{
    ArrayList items = new ArrayList();
    public object this[int i]
    {
        get
        {
            return items[i];
        }

        set
        {
            items[i] = value;
        }
    }
    public object Insert(object item)
    {
        return items.Add(item);
    }
    public void Delete(object item)
    {
        items.Remove(item);

    }
```

I have gone through the github link of .net framework at [Array in .net](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/master/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/Array.cs). But couldn't see anything regarding basic insertion and deletion of array elements, I see its internally using List. Can someone please help me in understanding is it possible to create a simple array ds in c#. May be my question framing is not proper but what I am trying to achieve is to understand how a simple array is implemted in c#

Comment: Arrays often do not have insert or delete operations. Also, [Microsoft Says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist?view=netframework-4.8) "We don't recommend that you use the ArrayList class for new development."

Comment: Side note: *generic*, i.e. `public class Arr<T> {List<T> items = new List<T>(); public T this[int i] ...}` is a *better design* (note *generic* `T` instead of `object`)

Comment: You can't implement the equivalent of a C# *array* at all easily. What you *can* do is implement the equivalent of a `List<T>` - but its implementation will have to use an array behind the scenes.

Answer (score 5):

An array needs to be resized when an element is added or removed.

The `List<T>` class uses an array under the hood and handles this for you.

If you are interested, you could take a look at the [actual implementation](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Collections/Generic/List.cs) on GitHub.

Comment: Yes, but what I am looking for is implementation of array . I wanted to know how an rray is implemented in c#

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/framework/tools/ildasm-exe-il-disassembler

Comment: @ganesh310: Look [here](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/blob/master/src/Common/src/CoreLib/System/Array.cs) then.